# Display popup if icon is clicked in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to make the `md-icon` display a popup when it is clicked.  The `ng-click` triggers `dismissNotifications`.  I can't use `confirm()` or `alert()` because it displays the checkbox, "Prevent this popup from being displayed on this webpage".  This will not work for what I am trying to do.  So I need to create a modal popup or something with a "Yes" or "OK" to confirm and a "Cancel" or "No" to deny when the icon icon is clicked.

HTML

```
      <md-icon class="rotate-clockwise-45 no-outline" style="color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;" md-svg-icon="images/icons/add_circle.svg" ng-click="dismissNotifications(app)"></md-icon>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.dismissNotifications = function(app) {
  var notifications = app.notifications;
  for (var id in notifications) {
    Service.dismissNotification(notifications[id].id).then(
      function(notificationId) {
        return function (response) {
          delete app.notifications[notificationId];
        }
      });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, create a `<div id = ..... class= ....>` and assign `style="display:none;"` inside the `<div>` create a table or just a message or whatever you like to display and create a **Yes, No, Close** button.

Write a function, and onclick of the `button` enable the `<div>` with
 `style.display = "block";`